# Python - Read emails?

Tags: python, string, email

I have the following code:

```
import poplib
mailServer = 'pop.gmail.com'
emailID = 'example@gmail.com'
emailPass = 'pw'

myEmailConnection = poplib.POP3_SSL(mailServer)
print myEmailConnection.getwelcome()
myEmailConnection.user(emailID)
myEmailConnection.pass_(emailPass)
EmailInformation = myEmailConnection.stat()
print "Number of new emails: %s (%s bytes)" % EmailInformation
print "\n\n===\nRead messages\n===\n\n"

numberOfMails = EmailInformation[0]
for i in range(numberOfMails):
    for email in myEmailConnection.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print email
```

The code is working.
I can read all my messages.
But my question is how I can get the body as a String?
Is it possible to just get the body text as a String?

Thx

Comment: Is what you are printing the body of the email?  Also, this question is tagged `python-3.x` but written in python 2

Comment: Consider reading about the Python [email](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html) module, which contains code for parsing email messages.

Comment: The parser is not working for me! :/

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I never used poplib myself but I did read the official docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html#poplib.POP3.retr

When you call .retr(i+1) here:

```
for i in range(numberOfMails):
    for email in myEmailConnection.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print email
```

retr(i+1) returns 3 values: `(response, ['line', ...], octets)`.
Here you take only the second value (by doing `.retr(i+1)[1]`), which contains a list of the message lines.

Just join all these lines to get a single string message by doing:

```
for i in range(numberOfMails):
    for emailLines in myEmailConnection.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print "\n".join(emailLines)
```

And if you want to parse the actual MIME content, you can use the `email` lib as suggested by @larsks